# iOS: Access Applet through an iOS application

Tags: java, ios, applet

I run a simple java applet on a tomcat server in eclipse. I want to access it through an iOS client app for my other requirements. I searched it, but couldn't get the right help. Could someone please guide me, how can i access an Applet which is running on a tomcat server, through an iOS program? Can I request through socket communication or any other from iOS client to Applet?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't.  An Applet is graphical program intended to be loaded by a browser via plugin.  There is no JVM on the iOS, so even if the first two parts didn't violate Apples usage requirements, the last would doom you.  If you want to access via some kind of web service through a native iOS application, that's a different thing

Comment: I'm asking through web service only.

Comment: An Applet is not a web service, it is a dedicate program which executed within the context of the client environment, there are significant differences

Comment: Yes, I'll connect a webservice from iOS client and that webservice should be able to contact the applet. Are you saying, even if the applet runs on a server, it can't be directly accessible through a Mobile app?

Comment: Nope, can't be done.  An Applet has a GUI, needs to run within JVM within the context of the clients machine/device.  A web service supplies text based and commands you give you.